# how to have ratchet communicate wtih android sdk api's

Tags: android, ratchet, ratchet-2, ratchet-bootstrap

[Ratchet](http://goratchet.com/) Looks real good for constructing easily `UI` for `android`.  However what if I need to have a `hybrid` app meaning I want some of my code to be written with `android sdk` for example open a thread fetch some data from `REST` then save to local store in android.  Then present this data on `ratchet` html table, not nessesaraly with `REST` but in general with `android sdk`

How is it possible to integrate the two? (`ratchet` + `android sdk` for example read some data from android local store and populate a table in html with ratchet? how should I approach this problem?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/) and write plugins.

Your native java code will live in a cordova plugin and use the android sdk. The plugin, once loaded, exposes these native methods to your javascript and can return data through callbacks.

The task of connecting to a REST api and saving it to local storage could be accomplished entirely in javascript using ajax and localstorage.